# Sent an HTTP request to Sharepoint in microsoft flow error: “Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl”

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-rest-api, flow, microsoft-flow

I am using HTTP request to Sharepoint in microsoft flow to get the image file from SharePoint. I am getting below error:

> {
>   **strong text**  "message": "Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl\r\nclientRequestId: fb4b8fad-a324-4e4f-9bae-9c887459adc7\r\nserviceRequestId: 9d57a39e-70e2-7000-8ba9-e2604dd27bdb",
>     "status": 400,
>     "errors": [
>       "-2147024809",
>       "System.ArgumentException"
>     ]
>   }

[image]

Please help to resolve this error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make sure that**

1. You have provided the correct **site address URL**
2. The file path is not started with a **Forward Slash** **/** that should be like this

> ```
> GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Temp Directory/NewIssue.png')
> ```